# Async Task for adding marker to android google map is stuck

Tags: android, json, google-maps, asynchronous

I have an android map that a launch with this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String breweryID = extras.getString("breweryID");

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

I then use an async task to get data to add to the map with this:

```
new AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON(this,map).execute(url);
```

When I run it, the map shows a dialog pops up to show its loading, but the dialog never goes away and the info does not appear on the map.

My async task looks like this:

```
public class AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    GoogleMap mapIn;

    public AddBreweryMapMarkerJSON(Context context, GoogleMap map)
    {
        c = context;
        mapIn = map;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting brewery information");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result, GoogleMap map){
        //decode json here
        try{

            Log.d("brewery", "in try");
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d("brewery", result);


            String longitude = getLong(o);
            String latt = getLatt(o);

            double longDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            double lattDouble = Double.parseDouble(latt);

            //add marker
            mapIn.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(longDouble, lattDouble))
                    .title("Hello world"));



        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String getName(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }



    public String getIcon(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("images").getString("large");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getDescription(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }


    public String getYear(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("established");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getLatt(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("locations").getJSONObject(0).getString("latitude");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "null";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getLong(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("locations").getJSONObject(0).getString("longitude");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "null";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

An example JSON I would get with this call is:

```
{"message":"Request Successful","data":{"id":"g0jHqt","name":"Dogfish Head Craft Brewery","description":"The story of Dogfish Head began in June of 1995 when we opened Dogfish Head Brewings & Eats, the first state's first brewpub opened in the resort beach community of Rehoboth Beach, Delaware. The plan was to bring original beer, original food, and original music to the area.\r\n\r\nNot only was Dogfish Head Delaware's first brewpub, it was the smallest commercial brewery in America. Our very first batch, Shelter Pale Ale, was brewed on a system which essentially was three little kegs with propane burners underneath. Brewing 12 gallon batches of beer for a whole restaurant proved to be more than a full time job. When the doors to the pub first opened, we brewed three times a day, five days a week! The one benefit to brewing on such a small system was the ability to try out a myriad of different recipes. We quickly got bored brewing the same things over and over that's when we started adding all sorts of weird ingredients and getting kind of crazy with the beers!","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfish.com\/","established":"1995","isOrganic":"N","images":{"icon":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/g0jHqt\/upload_WaJNQt-icon.png","medium":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/g0jHqt\/upload_WaJNQt-medium.png","large":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/g0jHqt\/upload_WaJNQt-large.png"},"status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:53","updateDate":"2013-08-24 13:07:38","locations":[{"id":"Mq24sa","name":"Main Brewery","streetAddress":"6 Cannery Village Center","locality":"Milton","region":"Delaware","postalCode":"19968","phone":"302-684-1000","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfish.com\/","latitude":38.770622,"longitude":-75.310893,"isPrimary":"Y","inPlanning":"N","isClosed":"N","openToPublic":"Y","locationType":"micro","locationTypeDisplay":"Micro Brewery","countryIsoCode":"US","yearOpened":"1995","status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:53","updateDate":"2012-03-21 20:05:25","country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"UNITED STATES","displayName":"United States","isoThree":"USA","numberCode":840,"createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:33"}},{"id":"57kBD4","name":"Dogfish Head Brewings & Eats","streetAddress":"320 Rehoboth Avenue","locality":"Rehoboth Beach","region":"Delaware","postalCode":"19971","phone":"302-226-2739","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfish.com\/","hoursOfOperation":"Open 7 Days, Year Round! Open at noon for LUNCH everyday, & we serve DINNER every night!","latitude":38.715362,"longitude":-75.086898,"isPrimary":"N","inPlanning":"N","isClosed":"N","openToPublic":"Y","locationType":"brewpub","locationTypeDisplay":"Brewpub","countryIsoCode":"US","yearOpened":"1995","status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-24 14:58:17","updateDate":"2012-03-21 20:05:25","country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"UNITED STATES","displayName":"United States","isoThree":"USA","numberCode":840,"createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:33"}},{"id":"hRSzMV","name":"DFH Alehouse, Gaithersburg","streetAddress":"800 West Diamond Ave.","locality":"Gaithersburg","region":"Maryland","postalCode":"20878","phone":"301-963-4847","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfishalehouse.com\/dogfish-head-alehouse-gaithersburg.html","hoursOfOperation":"Monday - Wednesday: 11:30am to 11:00pm\r\nThursday: 11:00am to 11:00pm\r\nFriday-Saturday: 11:00am to 12:00am\r\nSunday: 11:30am to 10:00pm","latitude":39.142971,"longitude":-77.215924,"isPrimary":"N","inPlanning":"N","isClosed":"N","openToPublic":"Y","locationType":"restaurant","locationTypeDisplay":"Restaurant\/Ale House","countryIsoCode":"US","yearOpened":"1995","status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-24 15:01:34","updateDate":"2012-03-21 20:05:25","country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"UNITED STATES","displayName":"United States","isoThree":"USA","numberCode":840,"createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:33"}},{"id":"JlBnVw","name":"DFH Alehouse, Falls Church","streetAddress":"6220 Leesburg Pike","extendedAddress":"Seven Corners Shopping Center","locality":"Falls Church","region":"Virginia","postalCode":"22044","phone":"703-534-3342","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfishalehouse.com\/dfh-alehouse-falls-church.html","hoursOfOperation":"Monday - Thursday: 11:30am to 11:00pm\r\nFriday - Saturday: 11:30am to 12:00am\r\nSunday: 11:30 am to 10:00pm","latitude":38.870041,"longitude":-77.151446,"isPrimary":"N","inPlanning":"N","isClosed":"N","openToPublic":"Y","locationType":"restaurant","locationTypeDisplay":"Restaurant\/Ale House","countryIsoCode":"US","yearOpened":"1995","status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-24 15:03:04","updateDate":"2012-03-21 20:05:25","country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"UNITED STATES","displayName":"United States","isoThree":"USA","numberCode":840,"createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:33"}},{"id":"w4ubfN","name":"DFH Alehouse, Fairfax","streetAddress":"13041 Lee Jackson Memorial Hwy","locality":"Fairfax","region":"Virginia","postalCode":"22033","phone":"703-961-1140","website":"http:\/\/www.dogfishalehouse.com\/dfh-alehouse-fairfax.html","hoursOfOperation":"Monday - Thursday: 11:30am to 11:00pm\r\nFriday - Saturday: 11:30am to 12:00am\r\nSunday: 11:30am to 10:00pm","latitude":38.880695,"longitude":-77.397333,"isPrimary":"N","inPlanning":"N","isClosed":"N","openToPublic":"Y","locationType":"restaurant","locationTypeDisplay":"Restaurant\/Ale House","countryIsoCode":"US","yearOpened":"1995","status":"verified","statusDisplay":"Verified","createDate":"2012-01-24 15:04:07","updateDate":"2012-03-21 20:05:25","country":{"isoCode":"US","name":"UNITED STATES","displayName":"United States","isoThree":"USA","numberCode":840,"createDate":"2012-01-03 02:41:33"}}]},"status":"success"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `onPostExecute()` method  is not overriden that's why its not getting call by it self try this.

```
@Override    
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        try{

            Log.d("brewery", "in try");
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d("brewery", result);


            String longitude = getLong(o);
            String latt = getLatt(o);

            double longDouble = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            double lattDouble = Double.parseDouble(latt);

            //add marker
            mapIn.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(longDouble, lattDouble))
                    .title("Hello world"));



        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Comment: thanks this gets it to run but it wont add the markers on the map. I will open another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

you onPostExecute is not an actual method of the AsyncTask class. onPostExecute takes 1 parameter so you created a method that never gets called because the AsyncTask does not know what that is.

Your return type is based on what you declare up here `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

so your doInBackground needs to have a return type of a `String`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

you need to remove the `GoogleMap` variable from your onPostExecute

Comment: Always use @Override so the compiler will generate an error if you're not actually overriding a method.

Comment: hmmm still not sure what I should change based on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onPostExecute` is wrong. The type in its parameters has to be what was returned from `doInBackground`. Your AsyncTask is looking for `onPostExecute(String result)`